# Full screen App in Android: a good practice?

Tags: android

Is it a good practice to develop an app that uses the full screen?

It is not a game, full screen would be just nice to have more space on the screen for GUI elements. 
But I have the dim feeling, that a full screen app could break some recommandations for good app design. The developer guide gives no answer to this. Who knows more?

I'm learning how to develop on android and it is very important for me to learn it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In his private [blog](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/07/how-to-display-android-status-bar-in.html) Reto Meier(Android Book author working at Google) advises everybody to not build full screen apps. These apps will blog the clock and the notification area and this will make the user unaware of every other app they are using.

I personally even dislike the full screen mode of some ebook readers because I read those ebooks at bus stops or in the train and I need a quick look on the clock while reading a book.

Don't annoy your users just for 30px of screen estate. 
If you think your design with this more space is perfect and every user will acknowledge this and wants to use it after trying it make it a setting to hide or show the notification bar. If you are using Google Analaytics you could even measure how many of your users are using this feature and then adjust the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, depends on the app. Personally, I'd get a little peeved if the notification area popped down over my "Angry Birds" and ruined the shot! ;)